# Python: "int not callable" with multiprocessing with pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

I had an error with some multiprocessing with the pool (pop index out of range) and when I tried to simplify my code to post it here I get another error, so it's kind puzzling, see the code here:

```
def some_function(a, b):
    return a*b

neigbhourhood = [[object() for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
result = [[object() for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
pool = Pool()
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        neigbhourhood[i][j] = pool.apply_async(some_function(i, j))

for k in range(0, 3):
    for l in range(0, 3):
        result[k][l] = neigbhourhood[k][l].get()
pool.close()
```

The traceback is about an int object not callable at the line 34 (the line with the get).

Edit: Ok it was just a typing error in the parameters of the pool.apply_async, now it's working but my real code is still randomly crashing and I can not repeat the error when I'm simplifying the code, I don't get it.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: It seems that the problem is not arising from "the line with the `get`", but instead your passing the function result to `pool.apply_async`. `some_function(i, j)` already computes the result, what you want to do is pass the function as first parameter and the function arguments as tuple, i.e. `pool.apply_async(some_function, (i, j))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you are calling `apply_async`. It requires you to pass a function callback and arguments that will be passed to the provided function.

```
pool.apply.async(some_function, [x, y])
```

Comment: Doesn't it return an ApplyResult Object (that I transform in int with the get() ) ? What should I do?

Comment: @RaphaelTodo `some_function` produces a result before `apply_async` gets called. So you will actually supply an `int` as callback function which obviously doesn't work